# How do I iterate through a .txt file and store the result in a 2d arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

The following is a snippet of a txt file

```
Patrick Joseph
1254367
cmt101
Introduction to Computer Science
1
Computer Science
Spring
2020
B+
3
cmt102
Computer Networks
2
Computer Science
Spring
2020
A
3
```

Every 8 lines minus the first 2 represents an attribute of a course in a college. I am trying to sort the data into two `arrayLists`, `course` and `courses`. `course` will be an `arrayList` containing attributes for each course while `courses` will contain all the courses such that the data in `courses` should look something like this:

```
[0][0] cmt101
[0][1] Introduction to Computer Science
[0][2] 1
[0][3] Computer Science
[0][4] Spring 
[0][5] 2020
[0][6] B+
[0][7] 3

[1][0] cmt102
[1][1] Computer Networks
[1][2] 2
[1][3] Computer Science
[1][4] Spring 
[1][5] 2020
[1][6] A
[1][7] 3
```

and so on. The program should be able to iterate regardless of how many courses are added to the file while skipping the first two lines

```
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> courses;
    public static ArrayList<String> course;  
    
    public static void getCourses(){
                try{
                    course = new ArrayList<>();
                    courses = new ArrayList<>();
                    String fileName = "C:\\Users\\myComputer\\Desktop\\file.txt";
                    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), Charset.defaultCharset());
                    for (int i = 2; i < lines.size(); i += 8){
                        for (int j = 2; j <= 10; j++){
                            course.add(lines.get(j));
                        }
                        courses.add(course);
                    }
                }
                catch(IOException io){
                    io.printStackTrace(System.out);
                }
            }
// courses is printed in another method
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use the same reference to the inner list which is filled with each iteration over and over. You need to create a **new** instance between the inner and outer loop and limit its scope. This will assure that a new instance will always be created and inserted into the outer list.

I also find no reason for instantiating these lists inside the method. Moreover, `ArrayList<String> course;` has a too broad scope and breaks the logic you intend to use. Lastly, program against the interface: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>()`;

```
public static List<List<String>> courses = new ArrayList<>();
 
public static void getCourses() {
    try {
        String fileName = "C:\\Users\\myComputer\\Desktop\\file.txt";
        Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), charset);

        for (int i = 2; i < lines.size(); i += 8) {
            List<String> course = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 2; j <= 10; j++) {
                course.add(lines.get(j));
            }
            courses.add(course);
        }
    } catch(IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. it is iterating the correct number of times but it is repeating the same data from the first iteration over and over. how can I fix that?